# Codeigniter 4 connection issue in gcloud MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, gcloud

I have deployed codeigniter project in google cloud app engine . I am trying to connect gcloud mysql via codeigniter. getting database connection problem. Database connection example is below -

```
public $default = [
        'DSN'      => 'mysql:dbname=db_name;unix_socket=/cloudsql/project:region:instance',
        'hostname' => 'public_ip',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'db_name',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => 'tbl',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8mb4',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

The connection IP of the instance is authorised?

I am getting `Main connection [MySQLi]: Connection timed out`

I have tried different things

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set hostname => to private IP because im using Ginstance.
DSN is not needed